# PCB strip from manufacturer

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication

When we manufacture certain PCBs, where 50ohms impedance matching is required the manufacturer provides a small PCB strip along with the actual PCB. What is the actual purpose of this?

Comment: Where's the photo?

Comment: To verify that the matched impedance is in fact 50 ohms. You can use a network analyzer or Time domain reflectometer (TDR) to measure the impedance.

Comment: @PeterKarlsen Spectrum analyzer can be used?

Comment: @PeterKarlsen I suggest you turn that into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To verify that the matched impedance is in fact 50 ohms.

You can use a network analyzer or Time domain reflectometer (TDR) to measure the impedance.

I'm not quite sure about this, but it might be possible to use a spectrum analyzer with build-in tracking generator to get an idea about the impedance. The phase information will be missing thou.